# Cumulant generating function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, simulation, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, moment-generating-function

I have a question, I consider the cumulant generating function given by the definition: Let $X\in R^d$
$$K_X(v)=\ln E[\exp(v^T X)].$$
If I have a random variable defined as: $$S=\sup_{t\geq 0}L_t$$ where $L_t=Z_t-ct,\ \ \ \forall t\geq 0$  (loss process) which $c$ a constant and $Z_t$ a compound Poisson process.

I want to determine the cumulant generating function of $S$, i.e.,
$$K_S(v)=\ln E[\exp(v^TS)]$$
but I am confused with the supremum, since If I have the product $v^tS$ I know that the supremum in this case is unique, then I can't do that since I have a vector $v$ and a number.

How to compute the cumulant generating function in such case?

Comment: Since $S$ is one-dimensional so is $\nu$.

Comment: In such case, I want to apply the exponential change of measure, I need that value in $$exp(\theta^T S-K_v(\theta))$$, I am not clear if this value is useful in my computations.